# Trying to append anchor tag from loop to div tag by id

Tags: jquery

[[image: Missing this next icon when i make it dynamic[1]]I am very basic to Jquery and I am trying to append values from for loop to `div` tag Id. As shown below:
I have a static `div` tag which shows images with next icon.
I am trying to make the `div` dynamic.
My static `div` looks like:

```
 <div style="display: none;">
    <a href="images/img-fancybox.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img"> 
        <img src="images/img-fancybox.jpg" alt="menu1"/> 
    </a> 
    <a href="images/img-toprelated1.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img"> 
        <img src="images/img-toprelated1.jpg" alt="menu1"/> 
    </a> 
    <a href="images/img-fancybox.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img"> 
        <img src="images/img-fancybox.jpg" alt="menu1"/> 
    </a> 
</div>
```

and jquery :

```
    jQuery(".beverages-images .menu-img, .block-dishofday .menu-img").fancybox({ openEffect : 'none', closeEffect : 'none', padding: 0, loop: false });
```

Here is my loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
{                   
 $("#food").append("<a href='Image' class='menu-img' rel='menu-img'><img 
 src='Image' alt='menu1'/></a>"); 
}
```

Here is my div :

```
<div class="scanned-menu beverages-images" >
    <a  id="my-id" href="img.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img" 
   onclick="getCategoryImage('drinks');">
    <img src="img.jpg" alt=img.jpeg"/></a>

    <div style="display: none;" id="food">


    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you want to append? and also food is display none

Comment: I am trying to make the div dynamic.I have static div something like this <div style="display: none;">
           <a href="images/img-fancybox.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img">
            <img src="images/img-fancybox.jpg" alt="menu1"/>
           </a>
           <a href="images/img-toprelated1.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img">
            <img src="images/img-toprelated1.jpg" alt="menu1"/>
           </a>
           <a href="images/img-fancybox.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img">
            <img src="images/img-fancybox.jpg" alt="menu1"/>
           </a>
          </div>

Comment: what is your problem specify that? also the code looks ok only remove display none from food div

Comment: It shows images on click with next icon

Comment: But when I make it dynamic I am not able to get that next icon

Comment: jQuery(".beverages-images .menu-img, .block-dishofday .menu-img").fancybox({
          openEffect  : 'none',
          closeEffect : 'none',
          padding: 0,
          loop: false
      });

Comment: Please edit your question with the additional information, don't add that in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Hay Manju this not exact solution but its kind of what you looking for.

```
<div class="scanned-menu beverages-images" id="fancy">
    <a href="images/img-fancybox.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img"> 
        <img src="images/img-fancybox.jpg" alt="menu1"/> 
    </a>
    <div style="display: none;"> 
        <a href="images/img-fancybox.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img"> 
            <img src="images/img-fancybox.jpg" alt="menu1"/> 
        </a>
    </div>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "demo_test.php", success: function(result){
            /** Here is you getting the result from ajax call suppose you getting JSON like. */
            let JsonResult = [{"image": "image1.jpg"},{"image": "image2.jpg"},{"image": "image3.jpg"},{"image": "image4.jpg"},{"image": "image5.jpg"}]

            /** After this you have to arrange this in fancy box */
            let imageString = ''
            JsonResult.forEach(val => {

                /** Arrange this data as you fancy box runs. First check with multiple static data then arrange it according that. */

                imageString += `<a href="images/${val.image}" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img"> 
                                    <img src="images/${val.image}" alt="menu1"/> 
                                </a>
                                <div style="display: none;"> 
                                    <a href="images/${val.image}" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img"> 
                                        <img src="images/${val.image}" alt="menu1"/> 
                                    </a>
                                </div>`
            })

            $("#fancy").html(imageString)

        }});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah but this is not exact solution

Comment: I am not able to show that next icon(img) when i make that div dynamic

Comment: okey ! as i understand, when you clicks next button ! then image is showing but `next button` is not showing right ? Or you want to dynamic images slider ?

Comment: No not even image or next button. Both are not getting displayed

Comment: okey ! now, how you getting dynamic images from `php` or `ajax` ? I mean if you have multiple images then from where you getting that images. that you want to arrange in slider ?

Comment: ajax, yes exactly

Comment: Here is it <div style="display: none;">
           <a href="images/img-fancybox.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img">
            <img src="images/img-fancybox.jpg" alt="menu1"/>
           </a>
           <a href="images/img-toprelated1.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img">
            <img src="images/img-toprelated1.jpg" alt="menu1"/>
           </a>
           <a href="images/img-fancybox.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img">
            <img src="images/img-fancybox.jpg" alt="menu1"/>
           </a>
          </div>

Comment: Here is the total div : <div class="scanned-menu beverages-images">
          <a href="images/img-fancybox.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img">
           <img src="images/img-fancybox.jpg" alt="menu1"/>
          </a>
          <div style="display: none;">
           <a href="images/img-fancybox.jpg" class="menu-img" rel="menu-img">
            <img src="images/img-fancybox.jpg" alt="menu1"/>
           </a></div>
         </div>

Comment: what are you using in back end ? and what is getting from ajax call (is that JSON, or array) ?

Comment: JSON @ Pushpendra Kumar

Comment: @Manju try this one.

Comment: Hey I have tried getting error at this   JsonResult.forEach(val => {

Comment: check `result` data type! if its string then use `let JsonResult = JSON.parse(result)`